# Delete the storage file in iOS

Tags: codenameone

Storage file cannot be deleted in iOS. The following works in android but the img gets displayed everytime in iOS.

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().deleteRetry(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "profile.png", 1);
```

I have tried the following but they dont work in simulator too

```
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "profile.png");

Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("profile.png");
```

The file is stored as follow:

```
URLImage.createToStorage(placeholderForProfile, "profile.png",au.profileImgUrl + getUserProfileImg, ada);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystemStorage` and `Storage` are two separate concepts which you are mixing together.

`Storage` only works with fixed names (not hierarchies, paths etc.) and `FileSystemStorage` only works with full paths.

This is the right thing to do when deleting a storage file:

```
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("profile.png");
```

If this doesn't work for you make sure you closed the storage file before and that you aren't using it. Also make sure you created it correctly as "profile" and didn't use paths.